# What command should I use to run tests, using testing-library withoud Jest - no React

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, testing-library

In my JavaScript project (no react) I'm using testing-library (without Jest), jsdom and jsdom-global to implement my tests. But when I run this command:

```
mocha --require jsdom-global/register
```

I get this error

```sh
(node:7696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Object.help (C:\Users\carlos.bravo\Desktop\proyectoArea51\area51-frontend\node_modules\yargs\lib\usage.js:240:22)
    at Object.self.showHelp (C:\Users\carlos.bravo\Desktop\proyectoArea51\area51-frontend\node_modules\yargs\lib\usage.js:432:15)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\carlos.bravo\Desktop\proyectoArea51\area51-frontend\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:53:13)
    at Object.fail (C:\Users\carlos.bravo\Desktop\proyectoArea51\area51-frontend\node_modules\yargs\lib\usage.js:41:17)
    at C:\Users\carlos.bravo\Desktop\proyectoArea51\area51-frontend\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:246:36
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:7696) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What command should I use?

Comment: Are you taking this approach? https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/setup#using-without-jest Did you try if [the example](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/example-intro) works in your project?

Comment: Yes I did, like I posted, I already installed jsdom and jsdom-global and execute this command "test": "mocha --require jsdom-global/register", in my package.json, but I get the same error :C